# Update BarChart Series dynamically

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to create dynamic BarChart from HashMap values. In my case I have `HashMap<String, Integer>`. I want String to be the name of the column and Integer the value of the column. I tried this example:

```
StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc;
    CategoryAxis xAxis;

    public StackedBarChart<String, Number> initBarChart()
    {
        xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        sbc = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        sbc.setAnimated(false);

        sbc.setTitle("Data Summary");
        sbc.setCategoryGap(55);

        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        testData();

        return sbc;
    }

    public void testData()
    {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) (Math.random() * 10); i++)
        {
            map.put("house" + i, (int) (Math.random() * 100));
        }

        createBarChartData(map);
    }

    public void createBarChartData(HashMap<String, Integer> map)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++)
        {
            XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
            XYChart.Data<String, Number> dataS1 = new XYChart.Data<>();

            Integer get = map.get("house" + i);
            series1.setName(tcp);
            dataS1.setXValue(tcp);
            dataS1.setYValue(get);
            series1.getData().add(dataS1);
            xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(tcp)));
            sbc.getData().clear();
            sbc.setData(FXCollections.<XYChart.Series<String, Number>>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(series1)));
        }        
    }
```

But I get empty chart. In my case I want to refresh chart values every second with dynamic series of data. What would be the best way to do this with minimum resources?

Comment: what is tcp? Whatever it is, you reset the category axis to it in each iteration (when you probably intended to add a category)

Comment: This is the name of the column. Just simple example.

Comment: simple isn't good enough - it must be a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem to have any value

Comment: Start here! http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Animatedbarchart.htm

Answer (score 0):

I hope you resolved your problem, but if not, you may follow this small [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Animatedbarchart.htm) which helped me a lot.

I got the same problem appeared. What I did is just:

1. used the `HashMap` as a datasource which I populated manually.
2. Then I passed all the data from it to `XYChart.Series series` .
3. By this I obtained `XYChart.Series` object which then I have changed dynamically according the logic of my program.
4. All of the changes where made through `Timeline` as shown in the tutorial.

Best of luck ;-)